# How fill the message box with js and press "send" key when "send" key is not visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, selenium, automation

I have a arduino+rasp pi project which require a command after 5 sec and i will send a message from my messenger to that arduino so trying to automate messenger but facing issue :

I am trying to fill the facebook messagebox and clicking send key but facebook messagebox is showing this div for message box :

https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/

```
<div data-offset-key="eoa6j-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj"><span data-offset-key="eoa6j-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span></div>
```

so i if i fill any text in message box it goes between `<span>"text"</span>` like this :

```
<div data-offset-key="eoa6j-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj"><span data-offset-key="eoa6j-0-0"><span data-text="true">hello</span></span></div>
```

I tried to fill the message box by :

```
document.querySelector('._1mf._1mj').innerText = 'Hello there'
```

It worked but send key is not appearing, "send" key appear only when any keypress event happen so how fill that box with keypress event so send button can appear?

I know that `data-offset-key="eoa6j-0-0"` is changing after every refresh but i have managed that issue , i want help to fill the message box with keypress event in console so send button can appear. and if possible click on send button. i also tried to `send_keys()` via selenium but didn't worked.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Basicly you want to make a robot script that posts your messages in the name of other people?

Comment: @Jerodev no i am trying to learn automation for sending a command to my arduino after each 5 sec.

Comment: In that case, it would probably be better to take a look at the Facebook SDK.

Comment: facebook sdk have many restrictions.

Comment: Can you manually trigger the keypress event? Like $(window).trigger('keypress'), or whatever element you needs the keypress event if not the window.

Comment: @TylerDahle i don't know about that method , please try in console of facebook messagenger here https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/

Comment: What I suggested would be put in your code below where you set the text of the messagebox. It may not be $(window) but $(whatever element needs the keypress event to be triggered to show send button)

Comment: @TylerDahle i am not expert is js , that's why i posted all things which i could try , please see the things and provide any solution if you can :)

Comment: I don't have the tools you are using readily available to assemble an example with a solution, so if you have one that can be shared and modified I can try... but otherwise it sounded to me like you want to fill the message box with JS, then automatically press the send key with JS after filling. And the send key only appears with a keypress event. So my initial take on a solution is trigger keypress with $(element).on('keypress, function()) (you can look up jquery '.on' function), then grab send key and trigger send key press.

Comment: Or utilize robot script, which facebook may have api's for? I haven't looked into doing robot scripts with facebook messenger so not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
 $('[aria-label="Type a message..."]).sendKeys('hello');
```